# Disable/remove a value in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In the below code I have a dropdown list with values I want to remove/disable product, but it doesn't work:

```
<editable:EditableDropDownList ID="dpval"  runat="server" Style="width: 70%; height:29px"  EnableViewState="true" onfocus="javascript: if(this.value=='--Select--'){this.value='';}" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='--Select--';}">
    <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>                                                 
    <asp:ListItem Text="Salt" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Book" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Product" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</editable:EditableDropDownList> 
<script>
     var myCombo = $('#<%=dpval.ClientID %>');
                    myCombo.append($('< option > </option>').val(1).html(option1Text));
                    $("#<%=dpval.ClientID %> option[value='3']").remove();
</script>
```

Comment: Where did you write this code? Is the append statement working?

Comment: @Pavan no it is not working

Comment: Where did you write this code? Under what?

Comment: @Pavan inside script tag

Comment: Can you update your post with the script tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not waiting until jQuery gets loaded.

Under script, write your code in the following function.

```
$(function(){
   //Your code goes here.
});
```

This gets called after jQuery gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need write those on DOM ready event like following. So that, script can work on loaded document elements.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // You code goes here.
    var myCombo = $('#<%=dpval.ClientID %>');
    myCombo.append($('< option > </option>').val(1).html(option1Text));
    $("#<%=dpval.ClientID %> option[value='3']").remove();

});
</script>
```